# Decompressed video file is not working in Java

Tags: java, compression

Basically i compress video using the customized compressor class in Java. I have assembled my complete code snippets here. My actually problem is, generated video [ A.mp4] from the decompressed byte array is not running. I actually i got this compressor class code over the internet. As i new to Java platform, i am struggling to resolve this problem. Could you please any one help me on this.?

```
public class CompressionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Compressor compressor = new Compressor();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        File file=null;

        try
        {
            URL uri=CompressionTest.class.getResource("/Files/Video.mp4");
            file=new File(uri.getPath());
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } 
        catch ( FileNotFoundException fnfe )
        {
            System.out.println( "Unable to open input file");
        }

        try 
        {

            byte[] videoBytes = getBytesFromFile(file);

            System.out.println("CompressionVideoToCompress is: '" +videoBytes + "'");

            byte[] bytesCompressed = compressor.compress(videoBytes);

            System.out.println("bytesCompressed is: '" +bytesCompressed+ "'");

            byte[] bytesDecompressed=compressor.decompress(bytesCompressed);

            System.out.println("bytesDecompressed is: '" +bytesDecompressed+ "'");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("A.mp4");
            out.write(bytesDecompressed,0,bytesDecompressed.length-1);
            out.close();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("bytesCompressed is: '");
        }


    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1064];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0)
        {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
}

class Compressor
{
    public Compressor()
    {}

    public byte[] compress(byte[] bytesToCompress)
    {        
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(bytesToCompress);
        deflater.finish();

        byte[] bytesCompressed = new byte[Short.MAX_VALUE];

        int numberOfBytesAfterCompression = deflater.deflate(bytesCompressed);

        byte[] returnValues = new byte[numberOfBytesAfterCompression];

        System.arraycopy
        (
            bytesCompressed,
            0,
            returnValues,
            0,
            numberOfBytesAfterCompression
        );

        return returnValues;
    }

    public byte[] decompress(byte[] bytesToDecompress)
    {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();

        int numberOfBytesToDecompress = bytesToDecompress.length;

        inflater.setInput
        (
            bytesToDecompress,
            0,
            numberOfBytesToDecompress
        );

        int compressionFactorMaxLikely = 3;

        int bufferSizeInBytes =
            numberOfBytesToDecompress
            * compressionFactorMaxLikely;

        byte[] bytesDecompressed = new byte[bufferSizeInBytes];

        byte[] returnValues = null;

        try
        {
            int numberOfBytesAfterDecompression = inflater.inflate(bytesDecompressed);

            returnValues = new byte[numberOfBytesAfterDecompression];

            System.arraycopy
            (
                bytesDecompressed,
                0,
                returnValues,
                0,
                numberOfBytesAfterDecompression
            );            
        }
        catch (DataFormatException dfe)
        {
            dfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        inflater.end();

        return returnValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code by compressing and decompressing a simple TXT file. The code is **broken**, since the compressed file, when uncompressed, is different from the original one.

Take for granted that the code is broken *at least* in the `getBytesFromFile` function. Its logic is tricky and troublesome, since it only allows files up to length 1064 and the check (throwing `IOException` when a longer file is read) does not work at all. The file gets read only partially and no exception is thrown.

What you are trying to achieve (file compression/decompression) can be done this way. I've tested it and it works, you just need [**this library**](http://commons.apache.org/io/index.html).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; // <-- get this from http://commons.apache.org/io/index.html

public class CompressionTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File("input.txt");
        File output = new File("output.bin");
        Compression.compress(input, output);
        File input2 = new File("input2.txt");
        Compression.decompress(output, input2);
        // At this point, input.txt and input2.txt should be equal
    }

}

class Compression {

    public static void compress(File input, File output) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        IOUtils.copy(fis, gzipStream);
        gzipStream.close();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }

    public static void decompress(File input, File output) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        GZIPInputStream gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
        IOUtils.copy(gzipStream, fos);
        gzipStream.close();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }

}
```

This code doesn't come from "credible and/or official sources" but at least it works. :)

Moreover, in order to get more answers, adjust the title stating your real problem: your compressed files don't decompress the right way. There is no 'video' stuff here. Moreover, zipping a `.mp4` file is no achievement (compression ratio will likely be around 99.99%).

Comment: gd1 :- Compression and Decompression is working fine for me for the video. But if i try to open my compressed byte of video it is not showing anything. But it runs..

Comment: With your code or with mine? In both cases, once you perform this kind of compression, the file is unreadable unless you decompress it. This is not video compression, it is a generic binary lossless compression, like WinZip. Compressed files

Comment: gd1:- With yours code only. Whether can we make compressed file to be readable by any methods ?

Comment: Actually your code destroys the file truncating it at 1064 bytes... However no, there is no way a ZIP compressed file can be played by a video player, even if it "originates" from a video. Once you compress it with ZIP, it should be decompressed in order to be playable again. Video compression generates 'playable' files because it's a radically different compression technology. If you want to perform MPEG video compression with Java, then you have to search elsewhere and there is not a single line of my code or yours that can help you.

Comment: It's a totally different technology, and it's orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: Do you know anything about MPEG video compression algorithm. If possible share me the resources or coding ?

Comment: Yes sure. Help will be much appreciated. I will also try over net.

Comment: @DavidBekham you can use a library that does mpeg encoding but i doubt that an description of mpeg encoding algorithm is any help for you. it is one of the most complex algorithms existing, and youn have  to study higher mathematics to understand it.

Comment: Out of scope then :).. Better i use this ..Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: what should be file extension in case of video file? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two tips:

1) Replace `getBytesFromFile` with a well known API call, either using Apache commons (IOUtils) or java 7 now provides such a method, too.
2) Test `compress` and `decompress` by writing a Junit test:
Create a random huge byte array, write it out, read it back and compare it with the created one.

Comment: and forget compressing a mp4 it is already best possible conpressed.

Comment: why removed the upvote? i told evrything what the other poster coded out: (use IOUtils, and test your compress / decompress)